# Any easy way to migrate emails from Thunderbird to Google Apps?

Tags: google, google-workspace, thunderbird

How do I migrate my POP3/Thunderbird account to Google Apps and sync it back ? Is there any easy method/tool to do this ?

Apparently I have done migration for Outlook users and I can't find any tool for Thunderbird migration.

Answer (score 1):

Just add your Google Apps account to Thunderbird using IMAP. Drop all your email from your pop account into an Apps folder. Your email should upload to that label.

Comment: Note this can be super slow and is not recommended by Google. https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en